# My API is sending data but its not getting stored in the backend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

So i was following this tutorial https://youtu.be/hISSGMafzvU, with different approach of mine ( instead of being a to do app, I'm trying to make it a clinic management system ).

So the problem I'm facing is that my api is receiving data, and there is no errors plus I'm getting 200 status code from the local server which means everything is okay, but its not hence the data isn't being stored in the DB for some reason.

this is the code:

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    fullname                   = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    age                        = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender                     = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
    choices=(('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female')), default='Male')
    usertype                   = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices=
    (('Admin','Admin'),('Doctor','Doctor'),('Receptionist','Receptionist')),
    default='Receptionist')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

class Patient(models.Model):
    fullname                   = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

class Appointments(models.Model):
    Paitent_Attending                = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    Doctor_Attending                 = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    appointment_date                 = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Paitent_Attending.fullname
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Employee,Patient,Appointments



class PatientSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'

class EmployeeSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'

class AppointmentsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointments
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def apiView(request):
    api_urls = {
        'Patient List':'/patient-list/',
        'Employee List':'/employee-list/',
        'Appointments List':'/appointments-list/',
        'Patient View':'/patient-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Employee View':'/employee-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Appointments View':'/appointments-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Add Patient':'/add-patient/',
        'Edit Patient':'/patient-edit/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete Patient':'/patient-delete/<str:pk>/',
        'Add Employee':'/add-employee/',
        'Edit Employee':'/employee-edit/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete Employee':'/employee-delete/<str:pk>/',
        'Add Appointments':'/add-appointments/',
        'Edit Appointments':'/appointments-edit/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete Appointments':'/appointments-delete/<str:pk>/',
        }
    return Response(api_urls)


#views for listing All
@api_view(['GET'])
def patientList(request):
    patient = Patient.objects.all()

    serializer = PatientSerializers(patient, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def employeesList(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.all()

    serializer = EmployeeSerializers(employee, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def appointmentsList(request):
    appointments = Appointments.objects.all()

    serializer = AppointmentsSerializers(appointments, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

#Views for Details 

@api_view(['GET'])
def patientDetails(request,pk):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=pk)

    serializer = PatientSerializers(patient, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def employeeDetails(request,pk):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)

    serializer = EmployeeSerializers(employee, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def appointmentsDetails(request,pk):
    appointments = Appointments.objects.get(id=pk)

    serializer = AppointmentsSerializers(appointments, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

#Views for Create New
@api_view(['POST'])
def addPatient(request):
    serializer = PatientSerializers(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def addEmployee(request):
    serializer = EmployeeSerializers(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def addAppointment(request):
    serializer = AppointmentsSerializers(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

#Views for updating & editing 

@api_view(['POST'])
def editPatient(request,pk):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=pk)

    serializer = PatientSerializers(instance=patient, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def editEmployee(request,pk):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)

    serializer = EmployeeSerializers(instance=employee, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def editAppointment(request,pk):
    appointment = Appointments.objects.get(id=pk)

    serializer = AppointmentsSerializers(instance=appointment, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

#Views for updating & editing 

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deletePatient(request,pk):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=pk)
    patient.delete()

    return Response("Patient was successfully deleted")

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteEmployee(request,pk):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)
    employee.delete()

    return Response("Employee was successfully deleted")

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteAppointment(request,pk):
    appointment = Appointments.objects.get(id=pk)
    appointment.delete()

    return Response("Appointment was successfully deleted")
```

the JS that sends data via fetch api.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

var form = document.getElementById('newPatient');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('form submited');
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add-patient/'
    var Fullname = document.getElementById('Fullname').value
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken' : csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({'Fullname':Fullname})
    }

    )
})
```

I'm still a newbie to the api world, I'm confused here, help!

Comment: Check if your serializer is valid if yes then check your payload inside your browser network tab.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari both are good, the api is working and storing data when i to it manually, which mean serializers is fine, and i checked the payload and its catching the data as JSON just like i want it.
but still its not getting saved in the database.

Comment: Hello @smokar *the api is working and storing data when i to it manually* - what do you mean when you say ***do it manually*** is it from postman or from django browsable api?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari when i go to certain endpoint like add-patient/ i get the default Django rest frontend, and i add the data in JSON format then i send a post request, and its saved in my DB.
but that's not the wanted method, like i don't want my clients to go throw all that process, i just wanted to have a simpler approach rather, but the issue is that isn't being saved in DB, i honestly don't understand why,
if i get an error its fine i can look the error code up, lol ( plus I'm not using postman )

Comment: Hello @smokar you're using browsable api ***"i get the default Django rest frontend"*** when you submit data from form it send all valid data if you send invalid data it will not submit your data & one more you want more clear error try this `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` it will raise error if your request data is invalid since you've not handled case when your serializer is invalid if you handle that then you can find where & what cousing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its one of those stupid mistakes that when you don't focus on the names lol.

The name of the addPatient property
`fullname`
, the fetch api was trying to send the data to
`Fullname`
capital F which doesn't exist, in which resulted in data not being saved because of this code in views.py

```
def addPatient(request):
   serializer = PatientSerializers(data=request.data)

   if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()

   return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer was receiving data, but because of the capital F it didn't match the addPatient attribute which is fullname not Fullname which resulted in serializer not being valid thus not fulfilling the if statement condition thus not saving the data xD, sigh